# How can I make a retro effect in the compositer like the one in this image

Tags: texturing, compositing-nodes, lighting

[image]

I saw this in this tiktok https://vm.tiktok.com/ZM8CXkt99/ and I wanted to achieve a similar effect. I assume they did this in the compositor, but even if they didn't, there should still be a way to get a similar look.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "retro effect" it looks like a render with some light bloom

Comment: What have you tried already? You should [edit] your question and share your efforts rather than only [posting a picture](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/what-is-the-problem-with-posting-an-image-or-link-and-asking-how-do-i-do-this) and asking how to do something.

Answer (score 3):

Well, the question is rather ambigious since we don't know how the original image looks like. But this one looks like a VHS look effect to me. There are numerous tutorials about that in the net if you search a little but they are all in softwares like Premiere, AE or Photoshop (...). You can watch one of them and adapt it for the Blender compositor, though.
I did an attempt my self and this is the before and after (Original image from pixabay) :

[image: Before]
[image: After]

You may tweak the settings according to your input image and your tastes but here, I'm just giving you the steps you may want to go through.

First of all, in Blender you can change the **color management** :

[image]

For 2.8+, the default value for `View transform` is at `filmic` and for 2.79 and lower, it defaults at `default` (it is labeled `View`). You can already change this value to `film` to see if it takes you closer to what you want :

[image: default]
[image: film]

In 2.79, you can find `color management` in `Properties panel` under the Scene tab. In 2.8+ you can find it in `Render properties`

Now, you could try to tweak the image's brightness and contrast using `RGB curves` and `Brigh/Contrast` nodes. Here I just bumped up the contrast and clipped the whites a bit (I also lifted the blacks a little bit) :

[image]
[image]

Now the process that will really give it that VHS look is what they call **Channel Blur**. It's a filter that allows to blur each channel of the image individually. We don't have such a node in Blender but, fortunately, it's really easy to implement. You just need to plug a **Combine RGBA** node to a **Separate RGBA** node and throw a few **blur** nodes in-between them like so :

[image]

Those are the settings I used for the blur nodes (once again, you can tweak them to fit your needs) :

[image]

After this, your image should look like this :

[image]

You can tint the image a bit with a color balance node by shifting the lift to a purplish color :

[image]
[image]

Using **Sharpen/Soften** can also be a good idea :

[image]

You can achieve this by softening the image before the channel blur and then sharpening it after like so :

[image]

I added another `RGB curves` node at the end to improve it a bit :

[image]

And the rest is up to you : you can overlay some film grains (tuts for that can be found everywhere), vignettes, chromatic aberration (...).

This is my final node setup (The blue frame you see at the bottom is just the noise texture I used to get the film grain effect) :

[image]

I hope it have been helpful to you.